Excel <- Sqlite, Use a cell value as month for query
I'm trying to extract an Excel Sheet from a Sqlite table, based on a query where 2 parameters from the Excel Sheet are used as inputs to the query:
select date(tsd.EndDate) as WorkDate, SUM(tsd.TravelHours) as TravelHours, SUM(tsd.SummHours) AS SumTotalHours  from TimeSignedDay tsd

where strftime('%Y', Workdate) = strftime('%Y',DATE())  - this is ok for now
and strftime('%m', Workdate) = strftime('%m',DATE())    - need to get month value from excel cell
and tsd.Contractor = ?                  - get value from excel cell works ok

I want to query by month (value from Excel field), but I cannot get any results; I presume its formatting..?
and strftime('%m', Workdate) displayed in excel is a 2 digit numeric ie '09'
How do I match this value to the excel cell?
